# CSS animation: shrink top image to reveal sub image

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

Effectively I have two images stacked on top of each other. After a timeout I would like the top image to start to shrink, not completely disappear, it will just become thumbnail. As the top image shrinks to become a thumbnail size, the bottom image is revealed.

My experience in CSS animation is zero, so what is the best course of action to teach myself the above?

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block__content">
        <h3 class="title--s">
            this is the title
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="block__image product-sale">
        <img src="/topimage" alt="topimage">
    </div>
</div>
```

the class *product-sale* contains the thumbnail:

```
&.product-sale {
                &:before {
                content: "text";
                height: 53px;
                padding: 10px;
                background: red;
                color: #fff;
                font-weight: bolder;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 999;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                left: 30px;
                font-size: 11px;
                }
            }
```

The code for class *.block__image*:

```
.block__image {
            min-width: 140px;
            position: relative;

            img {
                width: 400px;
                height: 200px;
                -o-object-fit: cover;
                object-fit: cover;
                padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px;

            }
}
```

My first venture would be to add a transition to the pseudo element?
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition2

Comment: can you add some code please?

Comment: @ATP I've added some code

Answer (score 1):

You can use @keyframes and animation in css to animate the image. I did not understand about the thumbnail you talked about but here is the code you can use it to animate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .sub img {
                width: 300px;
                position: absolute;
                animation-name: shrink;
                animation-duration: 4s;
                animation-delay: 5s;
            }
            .top img {
                width: 300px;
                position: absolute;
            }
            @keyframes shrink {
                from {width: 300px;}
                to {width: 50px;}
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="block">
            <div class="block__content">
                <h3 class="title--s">
                this is the title
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="top">
                <img src="/mm.jpg" alt="topimage">
            </div>
            <div class="sub">
                <img src="/m.png" alt="subimage">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it Helps!